# SQL query which will extract conditionally the values from top categories the first and the 2nd where CATEGORY is OTHER

Tags: sql, database, databricks, rdbms

I have this table. The table just a small example and has more obs.

| id | CATEGORY | AMOUNT |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | TECH | 120 |
| 1 | FUN | 220 |
| 2 | OTHER | 340 |
| 2 | PARENTS | 220 |

made by id category amount spent in each category.I want to select ID and Category in which the ID spents the most but in case if category is OTHER I want to get 2nd most spending category.
I have a constraint. I CANNOT use the the subquery and select with filter WHERE CATEGORY <> 'OTHER'. It just makes my machine to go out of the memory (For reasons Idk)

This is what I have tried.
I have tried to create a `row_number () over (partition by id order by amount desc) rn.`
and then
`select id, category from table where row num = 1 group by 1,2` 
**buttt. I don't know how to say to query. If CATEGORY is OTHER then take row num=2 . **

| id | CATEGORY | AMOUNT | ROW NUM |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | TECH | 120 | 2 |
| 1 | FUN | 220 | 1 |
| 2 | OTHER | 340 | 1 |
| 2 | PARENTS | 220 | 2 |

Another thing I was thinking to do is to write qualify function
`QUALIFY ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY AMOUNT DESC) <1.` 
Also here I am getting only 1st records in which there is also OTHER. If I could filter it out within QUALIFY and say if CATEGORY is 'OTHER' don't consider it.

I am using Databricks.

Comment: You have to use a `WHERE Category <> 'Fun'` - either before you number/rank the rows or after, so it probably amounts to the same either way.

Comment: Hi @topsail . Thank you for your answer. However I can’t use where category <> ‘OTHER’ filter because the databrics starts to crash

Comment: You will need to fix this problem with crashing - otherwise how do you filter out a category without being able to exclude it? Anyway, you need to figure that out anyway - your sql query writing ability is all going to severely restricted if you are not allowed to use WHERE clauses.